# Covering space Of unit circle is set of real number.(please help)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

The exponential function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{S}^1$ defined by $f(x)=e^{2\pi i t}$ is a covering mapping.
If we take a open set $U=\{(x_1,x_2):x_1>0\}$ then $f^{-1}(U)=\cup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(n-\frac{1}{4},n+\frac{1}{4}).$ That is every point of $\mathbb{S}^1$ has a nbd which is evenly covered by $f.$
But how can i prove $f|_{V_n}:V_n\to U$ is mapped homeomorphically onto $U,$ where $V_n=(n-\frac{1}{4},n+\frac{1}{4}).$??????
I can't understand it properly .Please please help .Thanks.

Comment: Do you already know that $f$ is a covering map?

Comment: Yes sir ...f is a covering mapping

Comment: $\left(n-\frac14,n+\frac14\right) \to U : t \mapsto e^{2\pi i t}$ is continuous. It has continuous inverse $U \to \left(n-\frac14,n+\frac14\right) : z \mapsto n+ \frac 1{2\pi i}\ln z$ (with the most common choice of branch). That is the meaning of "homeomorphism".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $f$ is a covering map. In particular $f$ is open map. Thus it suffices to show that $f$ maps all $V_n$ *bijectively* onto $U$. Since $f$ has period $1$, it suffices to consider $n = 0$. We have $f(x) = \cos (2\pi x) + i \sin (2\pi x)$. The functions $\cos$ and $\sin$ are well-known from calculus which allows us to conclude that $g(t) = \cos t + i \sin t$ maps the open interval $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ bijectively onto the open right half circle $U = \{ x + iy \in S^1 \mid x > 0 \}$. Thus $f$ maps $(-1/4,1/4)$ bijectively onto $U$.